# JMeter While Controller failing

Tags: while-loop, jmeter

I want to be able to run multiple iterations of this test plan.

```
Thread Group
While ${__javaScript("${user}" != "<EOF>",)}
  csv1 config
  If "${user}" != "<EOF>"
    Module Controller

While ${__javaScript("${user2}" != "<EOF>",)}
  csv2 config
  If "${user2}" != "<EOF>"
    Module Controller 2
```

When I run the test, at the end of the 2nd while controller, it outputs the following error: 
I've also tried running just 1 of the while controllers, and it has the same response. I'm not sure why it doesn't stop the current iteration and start a new one if it's able to get to the 2nd while controller.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:209) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller$1.run(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context$ContextCodeInstaller.initialize(Context.java:204) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase$InstallPhase.transform(CompilationPhase.java:508) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.CompilationPhase.apply(CompilationPhase.java:624) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.codegen.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:655) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compile(Context.java:1317) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:1251) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.compileScript(Context.java:627) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:535) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.compileImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:524) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:402) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:155) ~[nashorn.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.executeWithNashorn(JavaScript.java:142) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.JavaScript.execute(JavaScript.java:103) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:111) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:101)
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It might be connected with the test data, check the last line(s) of your 2nd CSV file, there might be a blank line or non-printable character which is causing errors.
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating to [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the While and If Controllers. The equivalent Groovy expression would be:

   ```
   ${__groovy(!vars.get("user2").equals("<EOF>"),)}
   ```

   where `vars` is the shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shortcuts
3. It's also [recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) (or whatever is the most recent stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I had an empty line. There was no error for few iterations (i.e 3 loops), but when running an infinite loop for duration and I'm still seeing an error.
Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.io.BufferedWriter.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at javax.script.SimpleScriptContext.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]

Comment: at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.getScriptContext(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]
 at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:136) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
 at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:111) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know how Loop Controllers worked, but I used them to solve this problem.

```
Thread Group
  Throughput Controller 
    Loop Controller (size_of_csv)
      csv config
      Module Controller
    Loop Controller 2(size_of_csv 2)
      csv 2 config
      Module Controller 2
```